# Calling F# function with a button from WPF (FsXaml approach)

Tags: wpf, f#, fsxaml

I'm trying to make a Button Hello World application with F#, WPF and FsXaml. I started following this guide:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-wpf-application-with-f-sharp-and-fsxaml/

Everything works fine when I just load things on xaml and compile, but I haven't managed to call a function by pressing a button and the guide ends before he explains how to call functions.

I've seen a lot of different kind of approaches around, but nothing has worked for me yet (and many of the guides are years old so a lot has happened inside frameworks since). It would be great to have a working (and simple) starting point on which I could start building once I understand the logic between x.xaml and x.xaml.fs when using FsXaml.

My button on MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Button x:Name="submitButton" Content="Send" Click="submitButton_Click"/>
```

Also I have this in window -section of MainWindow.xaml:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Views;assembly=GUItemplate"
```

My MainWindow.xaml.fs:

```
namespace GUItemplate

open FsXaml  
open System.Windows

type MainWindowBase = XAML<"MainWindow.xaml">

type MainWindow() =
    inherit MainWindowBase()

    override this.submitButton_Click (sender: obj, e: RoutedEventArgs) = 
        MessageBox.Show("Hello world!")
        |> ignore
```

The error I get currently:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
HResult=0x80131501
Message='Failed to create a 'Click' from the text 'submitButton_Click'.' Line number '29' and line position '101'.
Source=PresentationFramework

Inner Exception 1:
ArgumentException: Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type.
```

Comment: I haven't time to read your Q carefully right now, but I have a [sample project](https://github.com/FoggyFinder/GjlBindableQs/tree/master/GeneralDialog) with a dialog and there is a click handler for a button.

Comment: also, there is a [F# chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f)  - feel free to come here and ask Q about F# and WPF. Also I do recommend joining to [F# Slack](https://fsharp.org/guides/slack/)

Comment: Hmmm, that should work. Just to be sure, you can try adding `: unit` to the method signature to see if maybe the return type is currently inferred to be something else (although from the code you posted, that shouldn't be the case).

@FoggyFinder Your example is binding to commands on the ViewModel; the issue here is an event handler on the view itself.

Comment: The original FsXaml (and FsViewModule) were created with MVVM in mind. Which I consider a good idea, even with the steeper learning curve.
So, initially the only (and still best) approach was to use viewmodel commands, instead of code-behind handlers.
The fact that it wasn't evident to parse the event handlers either, will probably have something to do with the delay too. However, the latest FsXaml implements this as described [here](https://github.com/fsprojects/FsXaml/issues/55). Try `<Button Click="submitButton_Click" Content="Send"/>` and `override this.submitButton_Click (o,e) = ...`

Comment: @TeaDrivenDev there is also event handler: [override this.CloseClick (_sender, _e) = this.Close()](https://github.com/FoggyFinder/GjlBindableQs/blob/master/GeneralDialog/Program.fs#L20)

Comment: you can also try to go the next way: `type MainWindow() as self = ...` `do self.submitButton.Click.Add(fun e -> MessageBox.Show("Hello world!")  |> ignore`

Comment: code from the Q works fine for me

Comment: Thanks to everybody. I've tried everything listed in these comments, but it's not working. When I followed Foggy's advice, it compiled, but click is doing nothing.

Foggy would you mind to show your other code in case it worked for you? I would like to be able to reproduce that. There is something I'm missing.

Comment: please use notification `@nickname`, for example: @Foggy then member get message that one mentioned him.

Comment: I'll create sample and push it to github

Comment: done, there are two ways: https://github.com/FoggyFinder/GjlBindableQs/tree/master/FsXamlSample Both works for me

Comment: so, again, I can't reproduce the exception from the Q. Repo on github will be great to investigate the problem.

Comment: @Foggy Your code works! I can't thank you enough. I spent almost one whole day fighting with this button. It seems there is a lot of added complexity in the guide. Your example is so simple and elegant - exactly what I was looking for around the internet.

Comment: you're welcome. Feel free to ping me anytime

Answer (score 1):

This is how I proceed in VS 2017 and for me it works.
I add the `UIAutomationTypes` reference and I install the NuGet `FsXaml.Wpf`.

```
open System
open System.Windows
open FsXaml

type MainWindowBase = XAML<"MainWindow.xaml">

type MainWindow() =
    inherit MainWindowBase()

    override this.submitButton_Click (sender: obj, e: RoutedEventArgs) = 
        MessageBox.Show("Hello world!")
        |> ignore

[<EntryPoint;STAThread>]  
let application = new Application() in
    let mainWindow = new MainWindow() in
        application.Run(mainWindow) |> ignore
```